# Bubbling issue with delegated event on parent node with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, events, delegation

I'm having problems getting my event to bubble correctly I believe in a delegated event.

I have some markup like:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<!-- more HTML -->
  <div class="clear">
    <a href="#">
      Clear completed <span>items</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to add an event to `.clear`, and so I put put my handling code inside of a delegated event which is attached to `#wrapper`. My problem is that my event doesn't seem to bubble. In other words:

```
getElementById('wrapper').addEventListener('click', app.controller.update, true);

app.controller.update = function(e){
  console.log(e.target.nodeName) //returns either A or SPAN
  while(e.target.nodeName !== 'DIV'){
    //Infinite loop because no bubbling is happening
  }
}
```

Ideas? Yes, I can attach it directly to the element, but I'd like to keep all the events in a single container. And no, no jQuery.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're setting the capture argument of `addEventListener` to `true`?

Comment: No. I tried true and false to be sure. I've had it at false until I went to add this.

Comment: Your code does not show an element with the id 'wrapper', and there is only one e.target, so the loop is either infinite or uneccessary. If the target is the 'wrapper' element, do whatever.

Comment: Awh, good point about e.target. As for the id of wrapper, that was just a typo that i had `class` instead of `id` in the HTML above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event bubbling means that an event, raised on a child node can be handled by a parent node (if it is not cancelled by this child node).

`e.target` contains an initiator of an event. So, if you click on `span` or `a` tag it will contain references to these tags.
To check, if a click was initiated in `div#clear` you can try such a loop:

```
var el = e.target || e.srcElement;
while(el.nodeName !== 'DIV' && (el.id !== 'clear' || el.id !== 'wrapper')) 
// climb up to parent nodes until clear or wrapper is found
{
    el = el.parentNode;
}
if (el.id == 'clear')
{
    // Do smth
}
```